# Nesting controllers in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I'm building a Zend Framework application and created some controllers which correspond to database tables and hold methods for performing CRUD operations on those tables.

I've just started working on the `Companies` controller which holds methods for adding, editing and deleting companies. For this we can use the traditional `controller/action` URL pattern:

```
http://example.com/companies/add
http://example.com/companies/edit/some-company
```

The problem is that for each `Company` we also need to manage its `Contacts` and `Machines`:

```
http://example.com/companies/some-company/machines/add
http://example.com/companies/another-company/contacts/edit/some-contact
```

I just can't get my head around how to manage this in Zend Framework. Should I 'nest' the controllers through routing, or should I make use of modules? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily write custom routes to handle this. For example, this:

```
http://example.com/companies/some-company/machines/add
```

would become in your .ini file:

```
routes.machine.route = "companies/:companyname/machines/:action"
routes.machine.defaults.controller = machines
routes.machine.defaults.action = index
```

This will point the url to the `machines` controller and sets `companyname` as a GET-var.

You can easily change this to suit any form you like.

Answer (score 1):

with **zend** framework default router , your url's didn't work.
this links must work:

```
 http://example.com/companies/add
 http://example.com/companies/edit/id/some-company
 http://example.com/companies/addmachines/id/some-company//
 http://example.com/companies/contacts/mod/edit/companyid/another-company/
```

format:

```
http://yoursite.com/Module(if available)/Controller/Action/param1/val1/param2/val2/?param3=val3
```

Comment: The way you describe it, you don't create a `contacts` or `machines` controller? I would like to maintain some kind of hierarchy in the URLs, so the form `http://example.com/companies/id/some-company/machines/add` or `http://example.com/companies/id/some-company/machines/edit/id/some-machine` is desired. Is this possible?